# Sorted working differently with '&' in one of the list elements

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

if we have a dict and convert it

```
a={'pop': 1, 'Christmas': 1, 'R&B': 2}
```

and then we use sorted

```
sorted(list(a))
```

why does it return this?:

```
['Christmas', 'R&B', 'pop']
```

Comment: Because uppercase letters are sorted before lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a={'pop': 1, 'Christmas': 1, 'R&B': 2}
>>> list(a)
['pop', 'Christmas', 'R&B']
```

`list(a)` is the keys in the dictionary and `sorted()` sorts the keys.

Comment: Sorry I think you've misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

`list(a)` gives list of dictionary keys and `sorted` sorts it. Because your keys are a mix of uppercase and lowercase characters, you won't expect it to return in required way as uppercase letters are sorted before lowercase.

One way to handle this is to define a custom function like:

```
a = {'pop': 1, 'Christmas': 1, 'R&B': 2}

def lower(x):
    return x.lower()

print(sorted(list(a), key=lower))
# ['Christmas', 'pop', 'R&B']
```

If you are trying to sort by length of words, this would be the way:

```
a = {'pop': 1, 'Christmas': 1, 'R&B': 2}

print(sorted(list(a), key=len))
# ['pop', 'R&B', 'Christmas']
```

Comment: Gotcha, so that's what it does by default

Comment: Glad, I could help. Please press on tick on left of the answer, if you find it helpful, so others with same query can find a helpful answer.